# Eloquent laravel : how count data from json column

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi this is **Products** table

```
id | name      | price 
22 | product_1 | 10.00
33 | product_2 | 10.00
44 | product_3 | 10.00
```

and this **Orders** table.

in cartproducts column i have use json.

```
id|                 cartproducts                | summ 
1 | [{"productid":22,"quantity":1,"options":"[]"}] | 10.00
2 | [{"productid":33,"quantity":1,"options":"[]"},{"productid":44,"quantity":2,"options":"[]"}] | 30.00
3 | [{"productid":22,"quantity":3,"options":"[]"}] | 30.00
```

Using eloquent laravel how can i count how much order i have for each **productid** in **Orders** table using groupby method or other methods.

this is a simple imagine

```
$productorders = \App\Orders::where('productid',$productid)->groupBy('??')->orderby('count', 'desc')->get();
```

Desired output ( i will use my output in table sorted by Orders count )

```
product name | orders count | total earning | total quantity
product_1    |       2      |       40      |       4
product_2    |       1      |       10      |       1
product_3    |       1      |       20      |       2
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are making it hard for joining, and this table (Orders) as I can see it's only useful for logs. You can't join any other table to this table. Because you need to extract the corresponding values (ProductId and quantity) from the JSON field.

But even if you extract those fields, you can't handle the second record in Orders table, since you'll have two different productID, so you need to have an array field to extract the productId's into it, but then what you want to do with the array field, You can't really join it, and even if it's possible it'll make too way hard. for such small things.

I'll suggest stopping storing data which they eventually needs to be used as a joining key to other tables. You can store each item in OrderTable separately without using JSON.

There is a second solution which it's obvious, using PHP to handle the process in the application layer. You can json_deocde the contents of the orders and then the rest of the story which you know it.